# AsynsTask and FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I want to add an Array of Fragment in an AsyncTask like this (the code is in the doInBackground method):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfAlarm; i++) {

                    code = cursor.getInt(DATABASE_COLUMN_CODE);
                    id = cursor.getInt(DATABASE_COLUMN_ID);
                    Log.i("retrieve code databse", " " + code + " " + id);
                    arrayInstanceAlarmFragment.add(InstanceAlarmFragment.newInstance(code));
                    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.instance_of_alarm, arrayInstanceAlarmFragment.get(i)).commit();

                    cursor.moveToNext();

                }
```

But i have a problem at the line :

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.instance_of_alarm, arrayInstanceAlarmFragment.get(i)).commit();
```

It works but not in background thread, so i have a choregrapher warning like this:

I/Choreographer: Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I don't understand because the work is doing in the doInBakcground method of my AsyncTask ?

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: post your complete code.

Comment: I want to add multiple instance of a Fragment in my Activity, so i need a loop and, i do it in an AsyncTask. @DanielNugent Maybe you know how t add an Array of fragment to a viewgroup in my activity ?

Comment: I understand, my design is bad...It works not like this..

Comment: You know that you can create as many Alarms as you need, independent of any Fragment/Activity?